# How to insert child object with one to one relationship in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

**EDIT**

Ok everything I was doing code wise was correct I had placed the relationship on the tables wrong!

**Question**

I have a one to one relationship from task to message. When inserting new items I am getting a foreign key violation.

Details:

DB Structure

```
Task
    ID (Primary Key, Guid, Default = NEWID())
    MessageID (Unique Index with foreign key pointing to Message.ID)

Message
    ID (Primary Key, Guid, Default = NEWID())
```

The dbml settings for the primary keys on each table have Auto Generate Value set to `true` and Auto-Sync set to `OnInsert`

I have the following code to insert the new objects

```
    var objMessage = new Data.Message()
    {
        Body = "",
        Subject = ""
    };
    Context.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(objMessage);

    var objTask = new Data.Task()
    {
        Message = objMessage
    };

    Context.Tasks.InsertOnSubmit(objTask);
    Context.SubmitChanges();
```

This throws a SQL error foreign key constrain violated.

The SQL profiling shows linq to sql is inserting task before message which it can't do as it needs the id from message so of course this causes a foreign key violation.

Where am I going wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem what I can see is the first `InsertOnSubmit`. If you want to add it to the related table then I do not think you need the first `InsertOnSubmit`. Because when you insert the main object the child object will also be inserted with it's foreign key.

I think you can just do it like this:

```
var objTask = new Data.Task()
    {
        Message = new Data.Message()
                {
                    Body = "",
                    Subject = ""
                }
    };
    Context.Tasks.InsertOnSubmit(objTask);
    Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Yes this is the original way I did it and they way I expected it to work. I am marking your question as correct as it is :)  My problem was the DB in the edit like my edit says I had placed the relationship wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
var objMessage = new Data.Message()
{
    Body = "",
    Subject = ""
};
Context.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(objMessage);
Context.SubmitChanges();

var objTask = new Data.Task()
{
    Message = objMessage
};

Context.Tasks.InsertOnSubmit(objTask);
Context.SubmitChanges();
```

You must SubmitChanges before using the new record